# Agrupar datos en forma lineal en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Buen dia,
el problema es sencillo solo quiero que los datos no se repitan y me muestre un solo registro en el que los datos sean lineales, como lo he agrupado mal por eso sale un dato debajo del otro, quiera su ayuda para poder organizar bien la información y me salgan los datos por un solo producto.

```
(select t1.ACODIGO,t1.ADESCRI,t1.AUNIDAD,t1.Linea,t1.Linea2,t1.Estado from(
        SELECT  
          row_number() over (partition by decodigo,datepart(month,CAFECDOC) order by CAFECDOC desc, CATIPMOV desc ,CACODMOV desc,CAALMA desc,CATD desc,CANUMDOC desc,DEITEM desc)[Fila],
          DECODIGO as ACODIGO,DEDESCRI as ADESCRI,DEUNIDAD as AUNIDAD,
         (case when DATEPART(month, CAFECDOC)=MONTH(GETDATE()) -1  then cast(DEPRECIO as money)  else 0 end) Linea,
         (case when DATEPART(month, CAFECDOC)=MONTH(GETDATE()) then cast(DEPRECIO as money)  else 0 end) Linea2,
        case when (case when DATEPART(month, CAFECDOC)=MONTH(GETDATE()) -1  then cast(DEPRECIO as money) else 0 end) > 
        (case when DATEPART(month, CAFECDOC)=MONTH(GETDATE()) then cast(DEPRECIO as money)  else 0 end) then 'Aumento' 
         when (case when DATEPART(month, CAFECDOC)=MONTH(GETDATE()) -1  then cast(DEPRECIO as money) else 0 end) < 
        (case when DATEPART(month, CAFECDOC)=MONTH(GETDATE()) then cast(DEPRECIO as money)  else 0 end) then 'Disminuye' 
        else 'Se mantiene' end Estado
         from
         [025BDCOMUN].DBO.MOVALMCAB AS B INNER JOIN ([025BDCOMUN].DBO.MOVALMDET AS A 
                 LEFT JOIN [025BDCOMUN].DBO.MAEART AS M ON A.DECODIGO = M.ACODIGO) ON B.CAALMA = A.DEALMA AND B.CATD = A.DETD AND B.CANUMDOC = A.DENUMDOC
                 WHERE  
    /* AFECDOC BETWEEN '01/02/2010' AND '10/02/2010' MONTH(CAFECDOC)= 6  AND*/  YEAR(CAFECDOC) = '2020' AND 
   CASITGUI <> 'A' AND 
   NOT (CATD = 'GS' AND CACODMOV = 'GF' AND CASITGUI = 'F') AND 
   NOT (M.AFSTOCK = 'N' AND M.AFSERIE = 'N' AND M.AFLOTE = 'N') 
  AND DECODIGO like '100%' /*(DECODIGO >= '1000000' AND DECODIGO <= '1000000')*/
  AND (DECODIGO <> 'TEXTO')
  AND M.AFAMILIA >= '001' AND M.AFAMILIA <= '027') t1
        where [Fila]=1 
        group by [Fila],t1.ACODIGO,t1.ADESCRI,t1.AUNIDAD,t1.Linea,t1.Linea2,t1.Estado)
        order by ACODIGO
```

Los productos se repiten y los datos que son los costos no se muestran de manera lineal sino uno debajo del otro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberia quedar de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de como se deben de ver? Es de buena educación dar formato a tu código para que quede de una manera legible cuando vaya a ser revisado por alguien más.

Comment: A simple vista te puedo decir que acá: `group by [Fila],t1.ACODIGO,t1.ADESCRI,t1.AUNIDAD,t1.Linea,t1.Linea2,t1.Estado)` si deseas que no se repitan los códigos, deberías quitar del `GROUP_BY` todos los otros campos (linea, linea2, estado, AUNIDAD...)

Comment: @LuisCazares ya lo agregue compañero

Comment: @TomuRain totalmente al contrario mi estimado, al agregar el group by me ayuda a que no aparezcan mas registros de los que ya tiene

Comment: @guissepirodriguez Lee bien, no dije que quites el GROUP_BY, sino que deberías quitarle algunos parámetros. Por ejemplo, si no quitas el `t1.Estado` del GROUP_BY, el aceite siempre te aparecerá repetido 3 veces, porque está repetido en 3 filas en las que tiene 3 estados diferentes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Básicamente lo que necesitas es agrupar tus líneas para que queden en una sola. Esto lo puedes hacer con la función MAX(), asumiendo que siempre será una sola fila la que contenga el valor deseado.

Con un poco de formato, y moviendo el cálculo de la columna Estado, obtenemos algo como esto. Espero que notes la diferencia al tratar de enteder mi código y el tuyo, y eso te motive a dar un mejor formato al código que escribes.

```
SELECT  t1.ACODIGO,
        t1.ADESCRI,
        t1.AUNIDAD,
        MAX( t1.Linea ) AS Linea ,
        MAX( t1.Linea2) AS Linea2,
        CASE WHEN MAX( t1.Linea ) < MAX( t1.Linea2 ) THEN 'Aumento' 
             WHEN MAX( t1.Linea ) > MAX( t1.Linea2 ) THEN 'Disminuye' 
             ELSE 'Se mantiene' END AS Estado
FROM(
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY decodigo, datepart(month,CAFECDOC) 
                               ORDER BY CAFECDOC desc, CATIPMOV desc, CACODMOV desc, CAALMA desc, CATD desc, CANUMDOC desc, DEITEM desc)[Fila],
            DECODIGO as ACODIGO,
            DEDESCRI as ADESCRI,
            DEUNIDAD as AUNIDAD,
            (CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, CAFECDOC) = MONTH( GETDATE()) -1  THEN CAST(DEPRECIO AS MONEY)  ELSE 0 END) Linea,
            (CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, CAFECDOC) = MONTH( GETDATE())     THEN CAST(DEPRECIO AS MONEY)  ELSE 0 END) Linea2
     FROM       [025BDCOMUN].DBO.MOVALMCAB AS B 
     INNER JOIN ([025BDCOMUN].DBO.MOVALMDET AS A 
     LEFT  JOIN [025BDCOMUN].DBO.MAEART AS M ON A.DECODIGO = M.ACODIGO) ON B.CAALMA   = A.DEALMA 
                                                                       AND B.CATD     = A.DETD 
                                                                       AND B.CANUMDOC = A.DENUMDOC
     WHERE  /* AFECDOC BETWEEN '01/02/2010' AND '10/02/2010' MONTH(CAFECDOC)= 6  AND*/  
            YEAR(CAFECDOC) = '2020' 
     AND    CASITGUI <> 'A' 
     AND    NOT (CATD = 'GS' AND CACODMOV = 'GF' AND CASITGUI = 'F') 
     AND    NOT (M.AFSTOCK = 'N' AND M.AFSERIE = 'N' AND M.AFLOTE = 'N') 
     AND    DECODIGO like '100%' /*(DECODIGO >= '1000000' AND DECODIGO <= '1000000')*/
     AND    DECODIGO <> 'TEXTO'
     AND    M.AFAMILIA >= '001' 
     AND    M.AFAMILIA <= '027') t1
WHERE [Fila]=1 
GROUP BY t1.ACODIGO,t1.ADESCRI,t1.AUNIDAD
ORDER BY ACODIGO;
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias funciono a la perfeccion, mejorare con mi codigo, muchas gracias.